# Control Unity3D from Visual Studio application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unity-game-engine

i've been developing applications that uses `3D` engine to reder models mostly with `Ogre3D`. but now i want to start working with `Unity3D`, i want to have control like `SDK` from the app that i am developing. i want to:

- control the camera position and orientation.
- load and remove object from the scene.

i am fine with hacking so if there is a solution that is not so straightforward i'm fine with it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot directly integrate Unity into another application; it is designed to run as a standalone executable. (Correct me if this has changed...)

However, I did a similar thing with C#. In C++, the workflow would be very similar: I started a Unity application from the C# exe; the commands (e.g. setting the camera position) were then serialized and exchanged between the C# app and the Unity program via network sockets. Depending on how you design that network protocol, you can set and query all kinds of values.

Personally, I would recommend doing the serialization via JSON, since there are easy-to-use JSON libraries both for C++ and Unity.

If you want to really integrate the Unity display into your application, things get trickier. In my case, I had to start Unity in frameless windowed mode and re-parent it into a WPF control using some WinAPI tricks. This part depends on the GUI toolkit that you use, so I sadly cannot provide any help here.